# MSBuild - how to transform %(Compile.Identity) into filename with other extension?

Tags: msbuild, transformation

I'm kinda studying MsBuild. As a practical work I prepared a *.proj file to build simple "hello, world" C++ application. Things were gone well but then it fail after I added one line to "Compile" target - I cannot find how to make it prepare list of *.obj files to be used by linker.

**Note:*** Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.2558.0 (that is just a MsBuild.exe from "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" dir).

Here is my *.proj file:

```
    <Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">

        <PropertyGroup>
            <SourceDir>D:\BuildProc\cpp1</SourceDir>

            <OutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Bin\</OutputPath>
            <ExecutableName>MyCppSample</ExecutableName>
            [...]       
        </PropertyGroup>

        <ItemGroup>
            <Compile Include="hello.cpp"/>
            <Compile Include="main.cpp"/>
        </ItemGroup>

        <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="CopyFiles;Compile;Link"
            Inputs="@(Compile)" 
            Outputs="$(OutputPath)$(ExecutableName).exe">

            <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')" />
        </Target>

        <Target Name="CopyFiles" 
            Inputs="@(Compile->'$(SourceDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)')" 
            Outputs="@(Compile->'$(OutputPath)\%(Filename)%(Extension)')">

            <Copy SourceFiles="@(Compile->'$(SourceDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)')" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
        </Target>

        <Target Name="Compile" 
            Inputs="@(Compile->'$(OutputPath)\%(Filename)%(Extension)')" 
            Outputs="@(Compile->'$(OutputPath)\%(Filename).obj')">

            <Exec Command="@echo === %(Compile.Identity)" />
            <ExecEx Filename="cl" Arguments="%(Compile.Identity) $(CLOptions) -I$(SourceDir)" WorkingDir="bin" />

            <!-- here it fail! :-( -->
            <Exec Command="echo %(Compile.Identity->'%(Filename).obj') >> $(OutputPath)\$(ExecutableName).link " />

        </Target>

        <Target Name="Link" 
            Inputs="@(Compile->'$(OutputPath)\%(Filename).obj')" 
            Outputs="$(OutputPath)\$(ExecutableName).exe">      

            <Exec Command="@echo === Linking..." />
            <ExecEx Filename="link" Arguments="$(LibPath) $(Libs) $(LinkOptions) @$(ExecutableName).link" WorkingDir="bin" />
        </Target>

    </Project>
```

**Note:**  is a simple MsBuild task developed by me. That is just a simple wrapper for .NET ProcessStartInfo and Process classes. It works fine.

Targets Clean, CopeFiles are working fine. Target Compile also was working fine before I added echo command with redirecting to *.link file.

The problem is - it begins to report an error in Compile target after I added echo to *.link file:

Error message:

*D:\BuildProc\msbld06\build06.proj(73,9): error MSB4095: The item metadata %(Filename) is being referenced without an item name.  Specify th
e item name by using %(itemname.Filename).*

And here is a line in my *.proj file which lead to mentioned error:

```
<Exec Command="echo %(Compile.Identity->'%(Filename).obj') >> $(OutputPath)\$(ExecutableName).link " />
```

So, I need somehow to output {filename}.obj into $(OutputPath)\$(ExecutableName).link file and then use that file as @-parameter for linker. I tried to use other forms but all fail. So, searching for a hint...

In this case for me it is much more important to understand - how to achieve this with transformation exactly from %(Compile.Identity) if that is possible at all.
And only as a second step maybe you can recommend other way to do the same (my idea is not to use Microsoft.Cpp.targets or other include files, I want to do this with only empty/clean MsBuild setup).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Compile is ItemGroup so you should refer it with @ and not %.
Try following

```
<Exec Command="echo @(Compile)->%(Filename).obj >> $(OutputPath)$(ExecutableName).link" />
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work! First, it should be not a "@(Compile)->%(Filename).obj" but "@(Compile->'%(Filename).obj')". Second, both variants do not work. 
Here is an example of output it is producing: `hello.obj;main.obj;hello.obj;main.obj`. Linker input file expected to contain 1 *.obj file per 1 line.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish what you want to do ist to use the [WriteLinesToFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/writelinestofile-task) task:

```
<WriteLinesToFile Lines="@(Compile->'%(Filename).obj')" File="$(OutputPath)$(ExecutableName).link" Overwrite="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you. It works.
But I'm wondering - why the same statement `@(Compile->'%(Filename).obj')` does not workf or <Exec> command?! Well, using Reflector over Microsoft.Build.Tasks.dll I can guess - because Lines property of <WriteLinesToFile> task is an array. But... that looks a little bit idiotic from Microsoft team. :-\ Practically that means that expansion of the same parameter statement is very different for different tasks! Which is quite bad, I think.

Comment: so `@()` will return a `;`-separated string by default if passed to something that will end up as a string argument. `@(item->'%(metadata)', ' - ')` would separate using " - " . you could pass an encoded line feed there as well (`%0A`). Using `%(Compile.Filename)` would cause batching on metadata - for each unique value the exec task would be called multiple times.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you very much.